# Hamcrest test strange time shift failure

Tags: java, datetime, testing, jodatime, hamcrest

I'm trying to build https://github.com/jenkinsci/jira-trigger-plugin and have failures in tests related to time/date:

```
expect commentEvent.issue.creationDate, is(new DateTime(1980, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

Fails:

```
Condition not satisfied:

expect commentEvent.issue.creationDate, is(new DateTime(1980, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0))
|      |            |     |                |
false  |            |     |                1980-01-01T00:00:00.000+03:00
       |            |     1980-01-01T03:00:00.000+03:00
<...>
Expected: is <1980-01-01T00:00:00.000+03:00>
 but: was <1980-01-01T03:00:00.000+03:00>
```

As can be seen, the failure is due to the time shift, which is equal to the timezone offset.

But according to the timestamp, timezone is taken into account.

I have made a quick fix with JodaTime's .minusHours(), but this is not an option for a permanent fix.

Comment: "according to the timestamp, timezone is taken into account." - well, if a date is printed without any additional timezone info then it will use the default which is why both dates show the same timezone. However, they might have been created in a different way, e.g. `new DateTime(1980, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)` doesn't mention any timezone so it would use the default timezone as well - however `commentEvent.issue.creationDate` might have been created with a specific and thus different timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with jira trigger plugin so I can only speculate:

If the tests are not running in your timezone, probably they're not designed to do so (for 
whatever reason including bug in the test design).

If so, as a workaround you can consider running the testing process in GMT timezone (that has zero offset).

You can do so for any java process by using the following approach:

```
java -Duser.timezone=GMT <MainClass>
```

I don't know how does this plugin get built but I'm sure, there is an option to add the property like this for both maven/surefire and gradle

Comment: This didn't work for me.


I tried GRADLE_OPTS="-Duser.timezone=GMT" gradle build, JAVA_OPTS and "org.gradle.jvmargs=-Duser.timezone=GMT" in gradle.properties, result is the same as without parameters.


I'm sure the failure is due to test (or called method) that was not designed do run in different time zones. I would appreciate any guidance on how to fix it.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not a gradle expert, but one possible reason is that it spawns another jvm to run the tests. So you've acually changed the tinezone of the gradle process itself and not the process of tests. Can it be so? You can print the time in an artificially created test just to make sure that the timezone change works. Or alternatively run the test from IDE and setup parameter there